# How to catch an exception and recall the method in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, forms-authentication

What I'm trying to do is that I'm calling one WCF service (sever) from within another WCF service (client), server service has authentication and authorization mechanism,
when I call login method in server WCF it logged the client and creates a token that expired after amount of time, when that token expired an exception with "Access Denied" message thrown by server service.

What I want to do is to catch this exception in client service and recall the same method recalled in client with the same parameters after I do a login.
Do I have to use global error handler or IOperationInvoker class to handle it ?
I mean when my custom made token expired how could I know and recall the same method ?

Comment: http://pradeepc.net/blog/2009/11/04/getting-access-denied-errors-in-your-wcf-service-or-asp-net-application/

Answer (score 0):

You should build WCF service ready to [handle requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/05/18/600603.aspx)